# How to set data limit in mongodb collection?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I created a table/collection called prices in mongodb. I need to ensure that there is a maximum of 100 data in this table.
So, every time new data is added, the first data is deleted, how do I keep it constant with 100 data?

I just installed mongodb. I'm not sure how to do this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an option to set limit per collection on size or max number of documents in mongoDB called "capped" collection , check the details [here](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/capped-collections/#change-the-maximum-number-of-documents-in-a-capped-collection)
perhaps , cappedMax is what you are looking for ...